# using class as array in another class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am trying to do the following

1 - I need to create a class like this

```
public class base {
    int a;
    String b;
    public base() {
      a = 0;
      b = "";
    }
}
```

2 - I need to create a class that creates an array of "base" and sets some values

```
public class arrayBase {
    public base[] ab = new base[2];    
    public arrayBase() {  
       ab[0].a = 1;
       ab[0].b = "test1";
       ab[1].a = 2;
       ab[1].b = "test2";       
    }
}
```

3 - I need to use "arrayBase" in another class

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       arrayBase p = new arrayBase();
       System.out.println(p.ab[0].a);
    }
}
```

When I try this it gives an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: You need to create a new `base` object for each slot of the array. `ab[0] = new base();` etc.

Comment: Your `base` class would not compile.

Comment: **Suggestion for best practices:** please capitalize your class names (`ArrayBase` instead of `arrayBase`).

Comment: thnks ZouZou it solved my problem.

Comment: This is *not* Java... this is not even same zip code as Java :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
 public base[] ab = new base[2];
```

Here you are simply reserving heap space for two base objects, but you still need to create them and assign them to the correct array cell, like this:

```
  public class arrayBase{
    public base[] ab = new base[2];    
    public arrayBase() {  
       ab[0] = new base();
       ab[0].a = 1;
       ab[0].b = "test1";

       ab[1] = new base();
       ab[1].a = 2;
       ab[1].b = "test2";       
    }
  }
```

And please, name your class `Base` instead of `base`!

Comment: tnks for your warning this solved the problem as ZouZou

Answer (score 1):

For a recommendation,

```
  public class arrayBase{
  public base[] ab = new base[2];    
  public arrayBase() {  
     ab[0] = new base();
     ab[1] = new base();
     ab[0].a = 1;
     ab[0].b = "test1";
     ab[1].a = 2;
     ab[1].b = "test2";       
    }
  }
```

The class base needs to be intialized, also remember that you can only change the variable a and b if the base class is in the same package because of the default protected modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `arraBase` constructor as bellow. Problem there is, there are no object in the `ab` array, but, you try to access declared object's fields. First, you need to populate the arra with declared objects, then assign the value for the fields of those objects. And, Fix the compilation errors

```
public arrayBase() {  
     ab[0] = new base();
     ab[1] = new base()
     ab[0].a = 1;
     ab[0].b = "test1";
     ab[1].a = 2;
     ab[1].b = "test2";       
    }
```